# How to make a couple chart controls share all parent control space?

Tags: c#

I have some System.Windows.Forms.Panel that contains a few charts. I want to make all charts to fill whole form, so i use DockStyle.Fill for all charts. However, i see only first added control. How to make all of them visible with filling all parent control space proportionally? Can this be done automatically without calculating controls size manually?

Here's some example code:

```
     Button b1 = new Button();
     b1.Text = "LOL";
     b1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

     Button b2 = new Button();
     b2.Text = "OMGLOL";
     b2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

     this.Controls.Add(b1);
     this.Controls.Add(b2);
```

And here's result:

Actual

[image]

Desired

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `DockStyle.Fill` doesn't provide behavior you desire. You can try `DockStyle.Top` for first and `DockStyle.Fill` for second to get them one below another, but only later will be automatically resized to fill unoccupied form height.

Comment: Can you suggest me a common way to spread controls to all panel? Looks like i need to set each chart width manually.

Comment: Set `DockStyle.Top` for all charts and compute only height in `OnResize`. Widths and offsets computation will be handled by WinForms.

Comment: Sounds good. Will try this.

Comment: TableLayoutPanel is an obvious approach.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: Yes. I used DevExpress LayoutControl. After adding each control call .BestFit() method - after that all calculations on resize will work automatically without awkward maunal calculation of controls height.

Answer (score 1):

Change the docking for the one on top to be top and the one on the bottom to be bottom. Or create two panels and place them where you want and do dock fill for both. I usually do it in designer mode so I'm not sure of the actual code but it's probably just DockStyle.Top and .Bottom

Comment: Actually, i dont know how many charts i have at a time when creating a form. So, there's can be one or multiple charts on form, so i can't use designer mode as i understand.

Comment: It sounds like you will have to calculate it based on how many charts you have. But you can dock them automatically using top right left and bottom. Do you know the max amount of charts you could have? If it's more than 4 you could break up the panel into two panels and use the auto docks

Comment: No, i don't know exact number of charts. Gonna try to set .Size manually.

Answer (score 0):

For this task you should use a [`SplitContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Set it to `IsSplitterFixed = true` and `FixedPanel = None` and you are all set..

Now when resizing the `SplitContainer` its two `Panels` will be resized proprtionally.

You can now add the Charts with `Dock = Fill`..

If you need more than two Charts you can nest Splicontainers. For even numbers use 1:1 proportions, for odd numbers make one with 1:2 !

Answer (score 0):

My solution: use LayoutControl, add all necessary controls to it and call .BestFit() method after each adding. No OnResize event (with manual height calculation) handling needed.