# Padding a TableLayoutPanel from edge of Form?

Tags: c#

I have a WinForm in a C# program that contains two TableLayoutPanel controls. I have them positioned proportionately on the Form. There is about 25 pixels between the borders of the TLP and the Form. However, when I run the app, the TLP runs right up to the edge of the Form. I have the anchors set to Top, Bottom, Left, Right so the controls will resize automatically. But I'm not sure why the TLP runs up to the edge of the Form when it clearly shows in design mode a gap from the Form edges.

Comment: Use Panel container and anchor properties.

Comment: Put them in a SplitContainer, one per part. Then anchor them and fix the splitter; anchor the container, Now its parts will keep their proprtions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286758/how-to-make-a-couple-chart-controls-share-all-parent-control-space/34289493?s=5|31.3143#34289493)

Comment: That worked perfectly...thank you!

Comment: Taw, I'm not sure what I did but I broke it and can't seem to fix it. What do I do to "fix" the SplitContainer? As far as the TreeView/ListView go, I have them anchored to each Panel (all 4 corners) respectively.